# How to read plain text file in mule 3.8

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-module-jpa

In mule 3.8, when I use file connector to process text file , I am getting exception as below, please help.

Here is flow xml

```
file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true"  streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>

flow name="DW-FixedWidth-Processing">

file:inbound-endpoint path="D:/mule/input" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>

file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>

dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">

dw:input-payload />

dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=false
---
    ((payload splitBy /\n/)[0..8]) map {
    location:trim $[0..14],
    sku:trim $[15..39],
    dtc:trim $[40..42],
    tt:trim $[43..44],
    txnqty:trim $[45..54],
    um:trim $[55..56],
    rcd:trim $[57..59],
    te:trim $[60..89],
    ul:trim $[90..104],
    date:trim $[105..114],
    time:trim $[115..120]
} ]]>
dw:set-payload>

dw:transform-message>

logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

file:outbound-endpoint path="D:/mule/output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
```

Exception

Root Exception stack trace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No schema set at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.module.flatfile.FlatFileSettings.loadSchema(FlatFileSettings.scala:45)
>   at
>   com.mulesoft.weave.module.flatfile.FlatFileReader.ffParser(FlatFileReader.scala:42)

Answer (score 2):

When you disable streaming in the file connector, you no longer need the

```
<object-to-string/>
```

You can configure DataWeave to use a flat file schema, as already said in the other answer.

When you want to use it the way, you have to tell the correct mime type, in this case it is

```
application/java
```

You can do this on any message processor before the DataWeave, in this case the file:inbound-endpoint. Or you can do this in the DataWeave itself (unfortunately this is only visible when you switch Studio to XML).

For me everything worked with the following flow:

```
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>

    <flow name="dw-testFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="in" moveToDirectory="processed" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=".*\.txt" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
((payload splitBy /\n/)) map {
location:trim $[0..14],
sku:trim $[15..39],
dtc:trim $[40..42],
tt:trim $[43..44],
txnqty:trim $[45..54],
um:trim $[55..56],
rcd:trim $[57..59],
te:trim $[60..89],
ul:trim $[90..104],
date:trim $[105..114],
time:trim $[115..120]
}
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

The result of the DataWeave is a List of HashMap.

Comment: i have edited the details part to include flow xml , please have look

Answer (score 1):

DW does not currently support mapping from an unstructured string, even if you declare MIME Type = text/plain upstream and you set the input payload metadata to String in the Transform Message processor.

The data formats supported (as per [Mule documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats)) are Java, XML, JSON, CSV, Flat File, Excel, Fixed Width, and Cobol copybook.

The case here is clearly a Fixed Width format.

Comment: This helped me because I was setting a flowVar in a DW processor and the input type was String. If you do that you get the "No schema set" exception. Using a flowVar transformer with MEL in it works.

Answer (score 0):

@Prasad, generally the error `No Schema Set` at throws when the input mime type is no set. In your case, it seems like you are dealing with fixed width data hence you either define a fixed width schema. this [article](http://www.avioconsulting.com/blog/transforming-fixed-width-data-mulesoft) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i added mime type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to dataweave just use an groovy component to split payload by new line('\n').
Don't use file to string transformer it kills the Java-VM.
Also kindly brief what you need to achieve finally in your question.
Cheers!